# Bug in Chrome with window.getSelection() and :first-letter - any workaround?

Tags: google-chrome

The bug occurs only in chrome (tested in chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 under linux 64 bit / ubuntu 13.04), not in firefox (Version 22.0).

The problem is an incorrect Window.getSelection() in chrome which reports the selection index -1, so clicking with the mouse between the first and second character leads to position 0. It seems to handle the :first-letter styled character as a different dom element internally. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/c66kk/1/ as proove for this chrome bug:

```
<p class="initial">1234567890</p>

.initial:first-letter {
float: left;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-weight: bold;
}

$('p').click(function(){
    console.log(window.getSelection());
});
```

Is there any known workaround?

Context: I try to fix this bug for aloha editor. I also reported a chrome bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=266334

Comment: A first part of a workaround hack (detecting :first-letter) is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970137/detecting-first-letter-by-javascript but leaves open how to distinguish between position 0 and 1 (both are reported as 0).

Comment: bug report at aloha editor: https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/issues/878