# Detecting :first-letter by javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I need to know if an element is styled with a :first-letter style, and it should be a general solution so I won't depend on class names or special style attributes. Is there any way? Example:

```
<p class="initial">First</p>
<p>Second</p>

.initial:first-letter {
float: left;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-weight: bold;
}

$('p').click(function(){
    // how to determine if :first-letter is applied to current paragraph?

});
```

Comment: Why not just check if the `.initial` class is applied to the paragraph? If it's applied, then you know the `:first-letter` pseudo element style is applied - if there is a first-letter that is (and the browser supports `:first-letter`).

Comment: Because this should be a general solution as a workaround for a bug in chrome and must be used in a framework, so I don't know the style name.

Comment: I'd be interested to know about the Chrome bug. Do you have a link to the Chrome bug report ticket, or a jsfiddle that can demo it? Could there be any other way around it than the way you're trying? Also, if it's a known bug, is there a chance that they might fix it in the next release anyway? (have you checked if the bug is still there in the Canary version or the nightlies?)

Comment: Could be a way, and using jquerys selector functionality for comparing. Sounds realy ugly, but you may be right that there is no other way.

Comment: I send a bug report by the chrome://feedback feature and didn't get any ticket back. As a proove: http://jsfiddle.net/c66kk/1/ there you see that the window.getSelection reports wrong index values, see as reference my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952375/bug-in-chrome-with-window-getselection-and-first-letter-any-workaround

Comment: Thanks for giving the context; that's helpful (I've upvoted your original question, btw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your CSS is self-hosted, you can:

1. Get a list of all CSS blocks
2. Filter out CSS blocks which do not contain `:first-letter` in the block's selector
3. Iterate over the list of remaining CSS blocks, and run [`matchesSelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FElement.mozMatchesSelector) with the target element as a receiver and the current CSS block's selector as the argument.

   1. If `matchesSelector()` returns `true`, then the current CSS block's rules affect the target element's first letter.
   2. Otherwise move on to the next CSS block in the list

If the CSS isn't self-hosted and the CDN doesn't send CORS headers, then you cannot read the CSS file source
due to privacy issues and this cannot be done.

I have also left out figuring out rule-cascading from the algorithm. Another bump in the road is to figure out what pseudo-selectors affect `matchesSelector` in a false way.

Like consider:

```
p.webkitMatchesSelector("p:first-letter") //false
```

So one would have to remove pseudos like `:first-letter` from the string before attempting to match as these are irrelevant (but pseudos like `:nth-child` are not because they truly affect matching).

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/PBuzb/5/ (keep in mind the problems I mentioned are not handled really well here) (The base of code originally by Crush)

---

Why is it not allowed to read CSS source in cross-origin situation?

The reason you can only show images, run css/js etc.. from other domains BUT absolutely not access their data in any way is privacy.

The case is easiest to make for images. Let's say I am logged in to facebook, and facebook uses url for private photo like
http://facebook.com/myprofile.png. Now I go to evil.com, and evil.com can load the image because I am logged in to facebook,
the facebook will give them that image. Normally they cannot access the image or steal it in anyway, but if we enabled
cross-origin data access, they could now access my private photo and spread it out.

The same can happen in CSS, there could be user-specific CSS generated by the facebook server that contains user ids of my private
friends. They are not so private anymore if any website I can go to can just link to that css and start reading it.

And yes, the main issue is how browsers send cookies with cross-origin request, if the browser didn't send cookies when requesting
facebook images/css from evil.com, then facebook could not respond with user-specific css or my private photos because the cookies
were necessary to recognize me.

Now imagine if browsers didn't send cookies. Evil.com could still access any intranet data this way because my browser has access to the intranet. Being able to show `http://intranet/Myboss.jpg` as an image on evil.com  website is not a problem, but Evil.com being able to read the image data and thus be able to copy and spread it is a problem.

Comment: @crush lol yea I mentioned you now :P It is so tedious to write the code to get all css blocks so I wouldn't have made the demo without you so thanks :)

Comment: Does document.styleSheets not work for not self hosted CSS files without CORS headers, because I thought that's allready loaded and parsed by the browser, so there should be no security issues?

Comment: @SebastianBaltes The privacy issue is hard to explain in comments. I can write a paste bin.

Comment: @SebastianBaltes pastebin was down for me, so I explain it here http://jsfiddle.net/M9bdH/

Comment: @Esailija Just amend your answer to include the explanation - would make your answer more complete.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the cssRules, build an array of all the `::first-letter` rules, and then check if the element has one of these rules.

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PBuzb/2/) (Tested in Chrome only)

```
(function() {
    var firstLetterRules = [];

    var loadRules = function() {
        var stylesheets = document.styleSheets;

        for (var i = 0; i < stylesheets.length; i++) {
            var stylesheet = stylesheets[i];
            var rules = stylesheet.cssRules;

            for (var k = 0; k < rules.length; k++) {
                var rule = rules[k];

                if (rule.selectorText.indexOf("::first-letter") !== -1) {
                    //It is a ::first-letter selector. Add the rule to a list of ::first-letter rules.
                    firstLetterRules.push(rule.selectorText.toUpperCase());
                }
            }
        }
    };

    window.hasFirstLetterStyle = function(element) {
        var fullSelector = element.nodeName;

        if (element.className != '')
            fullSelector += '.' + element.className;

        fullSelector = fullSelector.toUpperCase() + "::FIRST-LETTER";

        for (var i = 0; i < firstLetterRules.length; i++) {
            if (fullSelector == firstLetterRules[i])
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    };

    loadRules();
})();

var element = document.getElementById("init");

if (hasFirstLetterStyle(element)) {
    console.log("Element has a first-letter style rule.");
}
```

Comment: There might be some cases that this wouldn't catch. Right now, it is only matching fully qualified css rules. I'll try to modify it to be even more forgiving. For example, it wouldn't match `*::first-letter` rule at the moment. and It wouldn't match `.initial::first-letter`. It assumes the rule would designate the tag name. I'll fix that in a second.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

Pseudo-selectors and their styles are not accessible from your JS code.

The closest you can do is check whether the element has the relevant class that would trigger the `first-letter` styles, and make the assumption in your JS code that if the class is there, then the `first-letter` style must have been applied.

There really isn't any other way, short of parsing your way through the whole CSS file manually.

This also applies to other pseudo-selectors and pseudo-elements (you'll find a number of similar questions around here asking similar questions about `:before` and `:after`, with similar answers)

Comment: Well you don't need to parse it manually, you can just use `document.styleSheets`. But that is the easiest step really.

Comment: well, maybe not necessarily doing the full parsing process, but you would need to go through each selector, find the ones with `:first-letter` selectors, and then work out whether your given element matches any of those. That sounds do-able, but could get messy quickly if you have a lot of CSS (and *very* messy if you have multiple `first-letter` styles applying to the same element)

Comment: finding out whether element matches given selector text is just call to `matchesSelector`, it is the corner cases and things like `*` not appearing in the selector rule text that's hard to get right :P